# Can I use Celery v4.0.2 with Django v1.7.1 without using djcelery?

Tags: python, django, celery

Currently I'm working on a Django project which is using version 1.7.1 which cannot be upgraded.

I want to know whether I can use the latest version (4.0.2) of Celery with this project without using `django-celery`?

Comment: djcelery is not necessary.

Comment: Is the latest version of Celery compatible with Django v1.7.1 ?

Comment: You can find the details in [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django). For versions < 1.8 you would need `celery 3.1`.

Comment: Hey, @WarLord I was wondering, did you found my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.2 of Celery you need to use `django-celery` for any Django version <= 1.7 project.

You can see this on [django-celery's change log](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/Changelog) at line 16:

> 3.2.0
>   ===== :release-date: TDB
>
> - Now compatible with Django 1.10
> - Dropped compatibility with Django 1.7 and earlier.
>
> For older Django versions use `django-celery` 3.1.x  <- line 16